# Safe to exclude ~/.local/share/zeitgeist in a home folder backup?

Tags: 13.04, backup, zeitgeist

Ubuntu 13.04.

I am configuring a home folder backup using Ubuntu's built-in backup function and Ubuntu One as the destination.

My home folder is fairly large, and I'm looking for folders that I can exclude without too much of a deleterious effect. That said:

As I understand, Zeitgeist is an activity logger - it has a folder at `~/.local/share/zeitgeist` which is large (~1.1 GB). What would the effects of not backing this folder up and having to run a restore later? Would they ever possibly include being unable to use my data?

For the curious, the other folders I am considering excluding are:

```
~/Trash (default) 
~/Downloads (default) 
~/eclipse-kepler (binary package only) 
~/.wine (losing this would not hurt my feelings at all) 
~/.cache
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zeitgeist is effectively an activity logger (it does some other things), and removing it is entirely safe, so i would assume not backing up its data would not be harmful to your system. You would only be losing a list of recently run applications and accessed files.

[More information on Zeitgeist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180990/what-is-zeitgeist-used-for)

Comment: I'm going to look at the source for it and get back to this - I want to know what those "some other things" are, but you've convinced me that it's safe to exclude. Thanks!

Comment: Note that under the Privacy section of Systems Settings, you can manually edit what is logged.